# Interpret a variable from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a multilanguage API and for this I need PHP to parse variables that are stored in an array.

In the database:

```
| Language | Type | Category | tId | Message                                |
=============================================================================
| English  | API  | Error    | 2   | Daily limit ($apiCounter) reached      |
| Dutch    | API  | Error    | 2   | Dagelijks limiet ($apiCounter) bereikt |
```

I've written an function that puts this information, based on a query, into an multidimensional array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Language] => English
        [Type] => API
        [Category] => Error
        [tId] => 2
        [Message] => Daily limit ($apiCounter) reached
    )
)
```

However when printing it the $apiCounter variable is taken literally and not interpreted as a variable.

```
<?php 
   echo textValue('English', 'API', 'Error','2')[0]["Message"];
?>
```

The outcome from the this is:

```
"Daily limit ($apiCounter) reached"
```

How to tell PHP it should interpreter the variable and show something like:

```
"Daily limit (2000) reached"
```

Comment: _“However when printing it the $apiCounter variable is taken literally and not interpreted as a variable”_ - well of course it isn’t ... that’s the difference between _code_ and _data_ that you are discovering here.

Comment: you could use eval() to accomplice this, but "when eval() is the answer, you're certainly asking the wrong question"  as wise man said. May be a str_replace() could help you?

Comment: I would suggest placing a text like "Data Limiet van (#amount#) overschreden" in the database, and let your application replace that string. Do not put information like variable names into your database. Think about resusablity of your database content

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `eval()` or a `preg_replace()` function for such a simple string replacement.

This will do the job efficiently:

```
$message = 'Daily limit ($apiCounter) reached';
$apiCounter = 2000 ;

$message=str_replace('$apiCounter',$apiCounter,$message);
echo $message;
// output: Daily limit (2000) reached
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/513f27a544ffe343bbb5b2af32ca42eef615bb85)